# AWS EC2 instance can only be accessible via port 80

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks, aws-security-group

I recently setup an ec2 Instance (**RHEL7.2**) on Amazon Web Services. I am having trouble getting it to respond to http requests. I run `docker run -p 12345:80 nginx:latest` successfully and I have added port 12345 to the inbound rules in the instance's **security group**. But this hasn't worked so far - I've tried both adding it to the default security group, and creating a new security group. And in local `curl http://localhost:12345/` works right.
But the **strange thing** is if I change `-p 12345:80` to `-p 80:80`, it works well!!! Then I have tried other ports mapping, **but the result is only 80 works!**
Has anyone else had a similar experience? Or give me some help and advice, thanks in advance!

---

PS:

- My containers:
      Image nginx 0:0:0:0:12345->80/tcp
      Image nginx 0:0:0:0:80->80/tcp
- Security group:
       All TCP     All TCP   1~65535  0:0:0:0
- EC2:
        Public IPv4: xx.xx.zz.zz

> I can access via http://xx.xx.zz.zz/ in browser and ssh via port 22. But http://xx.xx.zz.zz:12345/ failed.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of Security group , browser address of invoking that and o/p of docker container ls

Comment: Have you configured an nginx server block to listen to port 12345 in your server?